# When to avoid using accessor methods in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I keep seeing things like this in example Objective C code:

```
_myProp = newValue;
```

As far as I understand, creating a property `myProp` will create the actual variable as `_myProp`, and two accessor methods which are (by default) `myProp` (the getter) and `setMyProp` (the setter).

My question is, why do I keep seeing example code that by-passes the accessor methods and gets at the variable directly? Is there any advantage to this?

Comment: There has to be tens of dupes of this one, btw: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+ivar+accessor](Search for "[objc] ivar accessor").

Comment: @monolo I searched both google and stackoverflow for my question, but because I didnt use the word `iVar` I couldnt find any of these results. I tend to find there plenty of duplicate questions for Objective C, particularly for some of the error messages (SIGABRT and EXC_BAD_ACCESS for example). This indicates to me that the language is giving many people the same kind of problems, but I could be wrong. Do you think this is a problem with the language?

Comment: No, I don't think it is a problem with the language, but Objective-C _is_ different from other languages, partly due to its long history and heritage from Smalltalk. So instance variables (lazily abbreviated ivars) are called that, while other languages chose other ways to name the same thing. That is confusing, to be honest. A good introduction to Objective-C's idiosyncrasies (which aren't that many, after all) would be useful! BTW, the search seems to yield a similar result if done for "[objc] instance variable accessor", so the nomenclature is live and kicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are occasions where you don't want to declare a property and instead just use a private ivar.

If, on the other hand, there is a property declaration there should be no reason to directly access the ivar, except in the implementation of the accessors.

Sometimes people want to bypass the side effects of accessors and use the ivar directly. This is usually a sign of an architectural flaw, though.

Comment: What are the advantages of using a private iVar over declaring a property?

Comment: @Jimmery Ivars are used to define the private state of an object. With ARC there's little benefit in using a private property because ownership is handled for ivars as like for properties. Properties pollute the API of the class, so I recommend against them when used only internally.

Comment: How about properties that are declared in the .m file - if I understand correctly these are private properties. Are these private properties polluting the API of the class?

Comment: @Jimmery Yes. While being not visible to outside code they still reveal accessors to the runtime. If a base class privately defines a property "foo", no subclass or category can do the same (or use equally named plain methods).

Answer (score 1):

There are two times that I use the ivar directly.

1. When overriding the getter or setter. If you use the property self.blah inside the getter or setter it creates an infinite loop.
2. In the init method of a class.

Comment: Why do you access iVars directly in the init method?

Comment: In theory you should also use ivars directly in `dealloc` in case you need to do anything there anymore (with ARC handling most of the basic memory management).

Comment: Something I read a while back which I can't fully remember but it's something to do with uncertainty as to whether the getters and setters are instantiated fully or something. WIll try to find it.

Comment: @Jimmery Some people consider calling accessors from within construction/destruction problematic because a subclass that overrides the accessor might not yet be fully initialized and not expect the early call.

Comment: You also need to think carefully about KVO, especially in `dealloc` where there can still be observers around, but the state of the object is undefined.